# To MergeTwo hard drive.

Tags: windows-7

In my Laptop HDD is 500 GB .Partition are C with 50.20GB ;D,E,F with 138.49GB .My OS is on C Drive.I want to merge C and D drive.How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the D partition and then expand the C partition?

Take your data from D and "life-boat" it on one of the other drives temporarily if needed

Comment: This is correct only if your D drive partition is adjacent to your C drive

Comment: @Saariko : Agreed